# Function which returns a TABLE after splitting a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring, charindex

I want to create function which returns a table with two columns extracted from an input string.

As an input, the function gets a string like:

```
'@Name=John;@Secondname=Kowalsky;@Mail=example@mail.com;'
```

The function is supposed to create from this string two columns - x, y.

X for `@value` and Y for value after `=`.

I created this:

```
Create FUNCTION TwoColumnsFromString (
    @ReplaceString varchar(max)
)
Returns @temptable TABLE (x varchar(max), y varchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value1 varchar(max) 
    WHILE (LEN(@value1)) > 0
    BEGIN    
        SELECT  @value1 = (Select @ReplaceString)
        INSERT INTO @temptable (x,y)
        VALUES ((SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString, CHARINDEX('@', @ReplaceString), CHARINDEX('=',@ReplaceString) -CHARINDEX('@',@ReplaceString))),
            (SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString, CHARINDEX('=', @ReplaceString)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@ReplaceString) -CHARINDEX('=',@ReplaceString)-1)))

        SET @value1 = REPLACE(@value1, SUBSTRING(@value1, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @value1)), '')
    END
    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT *
FROM TwoColumnsFromString('@Name=John;@Secondname=Kowalsky;@Mail=example@mail.com;')
```

But that returns an empty table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The WHILE loop never executes because @value1 is null, only declared.

Comment: That helped! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost all your good work from your previous question :)

1. You should assign `@value1` its starting value *outside* your loop
2. Your insert computations should now reference `@value1`

Your function body should be

```
    BEGIN
      -- Set starting value outside the loop
      DECLARE @value1 VARCHAR(max) = @ReplaceString;

      WHILE (LEN(@value1)) > 0
      BEGIN
          -- We are now using @value1 not @ReplaceString
          INSERT INTO @temptable (x,y)
          VALUES ((SUBSTRING(@value1, CHARINDEX('@', @value1), CHARINDEX('=',@value1) -CHARINDEX('@',@value1))),
                  (SUBSTRING(@value1, CHARINDEX('=', @value1)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@value1) -CHARINDEX('=',@value1)-1)));

          SET @value1 = REPLACE(@value1, SUBSTRING(@value1, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @value1)), '');
      END
      RETURN;
    END
```

Comment: Yes, I've done that changes after comment:

"The WHILE loop never executes because @value1 is null, only declared."

But... "You lost all your good work from your previous question :)" - It hurts! :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this instead?

```
create function [dbo].[fn_GetKeyValuePairs](
    @ReplaceString nvarchar(max)
)
returns table
as return (
    select Left(a.[value], (CharIndex(N'=', a.[Value]) - 1)) as [Key]
         , Right(a.[value], (Len(a.[value]) - CharIndex(N'=', a.[Value]))) as [Value]
    from String_Split(Left(@ReplaceString, Len(@ReplaceString) - CharIndex(N';', Right(@ReplaceString, 1))), N';') as a
);
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016+

Comment: Did you test it with `'@Name=John;@Secondname=Kowalsky;@Mail=example@mail.com;'`?

Comment: Ops "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: @Sami I did, and purposefully left out the logic that would handle that particular edge case as the problem has many solutions; most of which are both obvious and trivial. Have updated the answer with an example of such handling to appease the peanut gallery.

Comment: @DaleK Yup, that's what I mean by asking him, and this code doesn't take the @ in `le@mail` into count.

Comment: @Sami Why would it need to? Inspecting the `@` symbol only complicates the parser because it **always** occurs after the delimiter symbol that was used to split the key-value pairs. As written, the only possible to way delimit keys from values; even *if* the code tries to add special, and unnecessary, handling for the `@` symbol.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 Read the question again.

Comment: @Sami Ok, done; what about the contents of the question did I miss? Sure, the OP mentions that the `@` symbol delimits a key (which they call `x`) but we can take that for granted and ignore such details in the parser. Again, this is because we can rely on the fact that an `@` symbol will **always** be preceded by a `;` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Working function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION MailReplacer20 (
@ReplaceString varchar(max)
)
Returns @temptable TABLE (x varchar(max), y varchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @value1 varchar(max) = @replacestring
WHILE (LEN(@value1)) > 0

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temptable (x,y)
    VALUES ((SUBSTRING(@value1, CHARINDEX('@', @value1), CHARINDEX('=',@value1) -CHARINDEX('@',@value1))),
            (SUBSTRING(@value1, CHARINDEX('=', @value1)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@value1) -CHARINDEX('=',@value1)-1)))

    SET @value1 = REPLACE(@value1, SUBSTRING(@value1, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @value1)), '')
    END
RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different strategy without cycles and using the `STRING_SPLIT` function available since 2016 in SQL Server.

My idea is to double split one as a structure and the other as a function, since it has two separator characters.

1. Implement a scalar function called **SplitValue** as follows

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION SplitValue
   (
       @Info as varchar(4000),
       @position as int=1,
       @separator as char
   )
   RETURNS varchar(8000)
   AS 
   BEGIN
       declare @Returnvalue as varchar(4000);
       with DataList as
       (
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ) AS ID,value as Returnvalue 
           FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Info, @separator)
       )
       select @Returnvalue= isnull(Returnvalue,'')
       from DataList
       where ID = @position
       RETURN @Returnvalue;
   END;
   go
   ```
2. Call this function from a query

   ```
   declare @InfoALL as varchar(4000) = '@Name=John;@Secondname=Kowalsky;@Mail=example@mail.com;';
   declare @position as int = 1
   declare @position2 as int = 2
   declare @separator as char = '='

   SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ) AS ID,
       value,
       dbo.SplitValue(value,1,'=') AS Name,
       dbo.SplitValue(value,2,'=') AS Name
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InfoALL, ';')
   where value <> ''
   go
   ```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ecb74/18)